# How to aggregate and fetch a record from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am learning MongoDB queries and try to do aggregation.
In case if I have list of records like below:

```
{ _id: 1, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 50 }
{ _id: 2, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-01T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 100 }
{ _id: 3, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 25 }
{ _id: 4, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-11T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 125 }
{ _id: 5, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-11-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 25 }
```

Then if I want to group above records based on `status` and need to fetch record based on maximum `amount`
So I need two records output from above collections:

`_id:2` should be fetched from `status: A` and same way `_id:4` should be fetched from `status:D` group.
Is there a way to do this?

I have gone through example queries in sample, they are grouping and calculating sum or average, so how we can achieve this.

Comment: Here are some Aggregation [$group examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#examples).

Answer (score 0):

To group documents, you need to use `$group` operator.

**Explanation**

1. We store inside `data` documents with the same status
2. We apply `$reduce` operator to get the document with the max `amount` value

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$status",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$data",
        initialValue: {
          amount: -1
        },
        in: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $gt: [
                "$$this.amount",
                "$$value.amount"
              ]
            },
            "$$this",
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EY3djw0DF8e) | [Alternative with $max](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mm42QIfbmEF)